# Converting a list of rules to a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

What are some easy ways to convert a `List` of `Rule`s

```
{"Joe" -> 94, "Jane" -> 85, "Bob" -> 82, "Bill" -> 83, "Michelle" -> 98}
```

into a `List` of `List`s

```
{{Joe, 94}, {Jane, 85}, {Bob, 82}, {Bill, 83}, {Michelle, 98}}
```

?

Comment: Do you also want to remove the quotations in your list of lists?

Answer (score 26):

```
list = {"Joe" -> 94, "Jane" -> 85, "Bob" -> 82, "Bill" -> 83, "Michelle" -> 98};

List @@@ list
```

> {{"Joe", 94}, {"Jane", 85}, {"Bob", 82}, {"Bill", 83}, {"Michelle",
>   98}}

which is a short notation, thanks @ Alexey Popkov, for

```
Apply[List, list, {1}]
```

Or

```
list /. Rule :> List
```

Or

```
Extract[#, {{1}, {2}}] & /@ list
```

Comment: Should that `Apply[List,list,2]` be `Apply[List,list,1]`. I took your example, went to the documentation, and found: The short form @@@ is equivalent to applying at level 1. Next, I tried `FullForm[list]` and your suggestion `list/.Rule:>List` made immediate sense, but `list/.Rule->List` also worked. Thanks for some great answers. Still working on the last one.

Comment: Actually `List @@@ list` is equivalent to `Apply[List, list, {1}]` as you can immediately see from `List @@@ list // Hold // InputForm`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated to correct this mistake

Answer (score 14):

for something different, for any list of rules e.g.

```
list = {"Joe" -> 94, "Jane" -> 85, "Bob" -> 82, "Bill" -> 83, "Michelle" -> 98}
```

then

```
list[[All, 0]] = List;list
```

will return what you want

Comment: Very neat, never thought of that!

Answer (score 5):

```
data = {"Joe" -> 94, "Jane" -> 85, "Bob" -> 82, "Bill" -> 83, "Michelle" -> 98};
```

As Eldo points out

```
List @@@ data
```

is most likely the best way to do this. But a destructing function would be fairly competitive. It also provides a direct visual representation of the operation sought, which makes it easy to come to mind.

```
f[k_ -> v_] := {k, v}
f /@ data
```

Starting with V10, there are two new ways to this.

```
Apply[List] /@ data
```

and

```
Association[data] // KeyValueMap[List]
```

The last is a little kinky though.

Comment: I got your function f utility to work like this: `data/.(k_->v_)->{k,v}`. And the last kinky one gives me an introduction to moving back and forth from associations to lists. Thanks. Nice answer.

Comment: I would imagine, that `Association[data]` may lead to a large overhead. That is, once an `Association` object is in memory, performing operations on it may be fast, but constructing the `Association` might be quite slow.

Comment: +1 My application starts with an association, and I need to convert `<| key -> val,...|>` into `{{key,val},...}`.  `KeyValueMap` is more than 50% faster than something like `List@@@(Normal@assoc)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
l= {"Joe" -> 94, "Jane" -> 85, "Bob" -> 82, "Bill" -> 83, 
   "Michelle" -> 98};
Transpose[{l[[;; , 1]], l[[;; , 2]]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`{"Joe" -> 94, "Jane" -> 85, "Bob" -> 82, "Bill" -> 83, 
  "Michelle" -> 98} //. {a___, Rule[s_ , f_], g___} :> {a, {s, f}, g}`

=> `{{"Joe", 94}, {"Jane", 85}, {"Bob", 82}, {"Bill", 83}, {"Michelle", 
  98}}`