# Applying a function of two variables to a the elements in a list of pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a function:

```
f = # - ((1 - #2)*a + #2*b) &;
```

and I would like to apply it to a list like this: `{{1,2},{2,3}....}`

I expecting to get a list of numbers.

Have anyone an idea?

Comment: try `f @@@ list`

Comment: at least closely related: [100700](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100700/5478), [10833](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10833/5478), [1970](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1970/5478)

Comment: Or `f2 = #[[1]] - ((1 - #[[2]])*a + #[[2]]*b) &; f2 /@ list`