# Referring to arguments passed to function

Tags: functions

Is there a way to get the arguments passed to a function? 
For example, I have the generic function `f`, then if I have

```
f[1,2]
```

I want to get `{1,2}`, and if I have

```
f[Sin[x],Cos[x],4,7]
```

I want to get `{Sin[x],Cos[x],4,7}`.
Thanks!

Comment: `[Sin[x],Cos[x],4,7]` is not a valid Mathematica expression. Maybe you can try `Sequence @@ f[Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7]` or `f[Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7] /. f -> Sequence` or  `List @@ f[Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7]` or  `f[Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7] /. f -> List`?

Comment: I meant the lists. `List@@f[...]` works fine! Thanks.

Comment: At least closely related: [Converting a list of rules to a list of lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100700/converting-a-list-of-rules-to-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List @@ f[1, 2, 3]
```

> {1, 2, 3}

```
List @@ f[Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7]
```

> {Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7}

or

```
f[Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7] /. f -> List
```

> {Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7}

```
f[1, 2, 3] /. f -> List
```

> {1, 2, 3}

Answer (score 0):

you can also do something like this:

```
f[arg__][p_] := p @@ {arg}
Through[{f[1, 2], f[Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7]}[List]]

(* {{1, 2}, {Sin[x], Cos[x], 4, 7}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! This one works too.

Comment: `p@arg` is simpler.